# Best way to optimize this view?

Tags: angularjs, optimization, view, angular-ui-router

I have a working view an I would like to optimize it. It is currently way to complicated.
The thing is that I don't know how is th ebest way to do it.

> Using function in controller ? Making a directive ?

Actually, the main optimization that can be done comes from links. I use ui.router and I have 2 states : deals.list and deals.list.selected.
For each link a the page, params depend on:

1. if a deal is selected
2. what is the current node category and if we have one selected, add full path slug tht can be 1 to 3 foldes.

It makes every link a bit compliated with lot of ng-if...

```
<div>
    <div class="column" style="width:30%;">
        <div ng-if="!vm.defaultNode">
            Affiner par catégorie parent
            <div ng-if="vm.deal">
                <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0]"
                   ui-sref="deals.list.selected({
                        dealId:vm.deal.id,
                        nodeId:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].id,
                        nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
                        nodeSlug2:null})">{{ node.title }}</a>
                <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1]"
                   ui-sref="deals.list.selected({
                        dealId:vm.deal.id,
                        nodeId:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].id,
                        nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
                        nodeSlug2:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1].slug,
                        nodeSlug3:null})">{{ node.title }}</a>
                <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[2]"
                   ui-sref="deals.list.selected({
                        dealId:vm.deal.id,
                        nodeId:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].id,
                        nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
                        nodeSlug2:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1].slug,
                        nodeSlug3:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[2].slug})">{{ node.title }}</a>
            </div>
            <ul ng-if="!vm.deal">
                <li ng-repeat="(key, node) in vm.nodes.data">
                    <a ui-sref="deals.list({nodeId:node.id,nodeSlug1:node.slug})">{{ node.title }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="!vm.deal">
            <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0]"
               ui-sref="deals.list({
            nodeId:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].id,
            nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
            nodeSlug2:null})">{{ vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].title }}</a>
            <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1]"
               ui-sref="deals.list({
            nodeId:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].id,
            nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
            nodeSlug2:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1].slug,
            nodeSlug3:null})">{{ vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1].title }}</a>
            <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[2]"
               ui-sref="deals.list({
            nodeId:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].id,
            nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
            nodeSlug2:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1].slug,
            nodeSlug3:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[2].slug})">{{ vm.nodeTree.ancestors[2].title }}</a>
        </div>
        <div>{{vm.nodeTree.title}}</div>

    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <select ng-model="vm.order" ng-init="vm.order=vm.defaultOrder" ng-change="vm.changeOrderTo(vm.order)">
            <option value="hottest">order by: hottest</option>
            <option value="newest">order by: newest</option>
        </select>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="deal in vm.deals.data">
                <a ng-if="!vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0]"
                    ui-sref="deals.list.selected({
                        dealId:deal.id,
                        nodeId:vm.nodeTree.id,
                        nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.slug})">{{ deal.title }}</a>
                <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0]"
                   ui-sref="deals.list.selected({
                        dealId:deal.id,
                        nodeId:vm.nodeTree.id,
                        nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
                        nodeSlug2:vm.nodeTree.slug})">{{ deal.title }}</a>
                <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1]"
                   ui-sref="deals.list.selected({
                        dealId:deal.id,
                        nodeId:vm.nodeTree.id,
                        nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
                        nodeSlug2:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1].slug,
                        nodeSlug3:vm.nodeTree.slug})">{{ deal.title }}</a>
                <a ng-if="vm.nodeTree.ancestors[2]"
                   ui-sref="deals.list.selected({
                        dealId:deal.id,
                        nodeId:vm.nodeTree.id,
                        nodeSlug1:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[0].slug,
                        nodeSlug2:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[1].slug,
                        nodeSlug3:vm.nodeTree.ancestors[2].slug})">{{ deal.title }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong answer but since you have template html involved I would steer towards a directive. However, if I were doing this I would implement it in Angular using Googles Polymer. Polymer makes the shadow DOM available now. The thinking is similar to an Angular directive allowing partial HTML to be templated. Worth a look. The advantage over a directive is you don't end up with a controller file and a template file and a css file but can throw it altogether in one shadow DOM encapsulated solution.

Comment: I did not know polymer before your answer. Thanks for that. Seems to me that it's going to load another lib tu make polymer work and I really need to keep the app thin. I guess directive it is then. Thanks for your answer !